# Using python to launch and kill batch files isn't killing the batch files

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm writing a python script that will launch batch files, kill those batch files, move log files into the proper location, and repeat.

My problem is: I can launch the first batch file but not kill it.  I launch with

```
mapPath = "removed\\for\\reading\\Random.bat"
map = subprocess.Popen(mapPath, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then I'll launch another batch file, e.g.,

```
bat = os.system("batch1.bat")
```

and batch1.bat should kill itself when it's done.  The 'map' process I ran first will not; I need to kill that so that it stops touching the last log file it's been writing to, and then I can start moving files.

I've tried commands to kill(), terminate(), TerminateProcess(), sending SIGINT with os.kill, sending 0 with os.kill, and communicating various things like 'taskkill /f' to the pid.  The only thing I can think of is that I need to kill the program the original batch file is launching, but I've tried writing another batch file to kill the programs it might launch but running that batch file keeps giving me an invalid query message.

Ideas?  Are there more commands to try to kill the batch file, or should I keep trying to kill the processes instead of the batch file I originally launch?  I'm using python 3.3.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you using creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP ? This should allow CTRL-C events to be passed to the batch and on to all its children.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that right away.  I added that flag to my Popen, but it hasn't helped terminate, kill, or sending taskkill.  I thought I had tried sending a Ctrl+C but I can't find that now.  Would that only help Ctrl+C?

Comment: Most things meant for execution from a console/batch should respond to Ctrl+C. I think other signals should pass through too.

Comment: Using "os.kill(map.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)" generates an error for me; not sure what to attempt next (this is with creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\queue.py", line 176, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 288, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: I wold try it from the command line, just in case.

Comment: You mean run os.kill(map.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) from a new Python shell?  I did that (substituted the actual PID for map.pid) and it spits the handle invalid error.

Comment: No, I meant not using IDLE to run this, since tasks may need to be associated with an actual console and command line in order to receive Ctrl+C. I cannot check this on my linux box. You may be able to use the psutil package to explicitly find the children of your batch job, and kill them individually.

Answer (score 0):

What is the batch file doing that is not allowing it to end? It seems like that is the problem to me.

Comment: Nothing that shouldn't be killable.  It launches a program called Repast that another thing uses to run simulations on.